# YII2 Insert records selected from one grid to another

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, crud

i'm new in Yii2, previously i use self-made-mvc-php + extjs 4.2

So i working on Yii2 now, i'm starting to get the hang of it for simple CRUD, my pobrem starts when i need to make entry form for parent-child tables.
I have 3 tables

1. commission

   > commission_id 
   >   commission_name 
   >   commission_amount 
   >   commission_percent
2. commission_scheme

   > cscheme_id 
   >   cscheme_name 
   >   cscheme_amount 
   >   cscheme_percent 
   >   cscheme_bonus 
   >   cscheme_description
3. commission_scheme_detail

   > cscheme_detail_id 
   >   commission_id 
   >   cscheme_id

The entry form is for commission_scheme and commission_scheme_detail.

- I have generated all the crud using gii
- i modify _form.php, add a gridview of commission_scheme_detail after the active form
- i also add modal containing selection grid from commission

this is _form.php 
**gridview**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjaxCschemedetail', 
                                'timeout' => false,
                                'enablePushState' => false, 
                                'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']
                                ]); 
            echo GridView::widget([
                'id'        => 'gridCschemedetail',
                'dataProvider' => $detailData,
                'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    'CSCHEME_DETAIL_ID',
                    'CSCHEME_ID',
                    'COMMISSION_ID',

                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                        'buttons' => [
                        'update' => function ($url, $model) {

                                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['commission-scheme-detail/view','id' => $model->CSCHEME_DETAIL_ID,'edit'=>'t']), [
                                                            'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Edit'),
                                                          ]);}

                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'responsive'=>true,
                'hover'=>true,
                'condensed'=>true,
                'floatHeader'=>true,




                'panel' => [
                    'type'=>'info',
                    'before'=>  
                                                                                                                                                          'after'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Reset List', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
                                Html::button('Add', [
                                    'id'    => 'addDetailButton',
                                    'class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn btn-success btn-ajax-modal',
                                    'value' => Url::to('@web/commission/listselect'),
                                    'data-target' => '#modal_cschemedetail',
                                ]), 

                    'showFooter'=>false
                ],
            ]); Pjax::end();
```

**Modal**

```
Modal::begin([
                'id' => 'modal_cschemedetail',
                'header' => '<h4>Category</h4>',
            ]);
            echo '<div id="modal-content"></div>';
            echo Html::button('Add Selected', [
                                    'id'    => 'addCommissionsButton',
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-ajax-modal'
                                ]);
            Modal::end();
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

**selection grid**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); echo GridView::widget([
    'id'        =>  'gridCommissionSelection',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
            'attribute' => 'COMMISSION_ID',
            'visible'   =>  false
        ],
        'COMMISSION_NAME',
        [
            'attribute' => 'TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID',
            'value' => 'transactionTypeName'
        ],
        'COMMISSION_DESC:ntext',
        'COMMISSION_AMOUNT',
    ]
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'condensed'=>true,
    'floatHeader'=>true,

]); Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Is it possible to insert the selected records from the modal to the detail gridview, then after user click the create button, the form and the inserted records in gridview saved to respective tables? 

How can i insert the selected records to gridview (not to db table, it will be done after user click create)?

Comment: Remember to always create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially remember the ***minimal*** part.

Comment: Oh, right i'll edit it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to simplify your flow. You can easily save your models (performing an insert/update) at `Modal` and then refresh the page or call the `$.pjax.reload('#gridCommissionSelection')` to redraw the grid-view with new entries.

Another way is to append new lines with JS and then save them via AJAX request. It will be rather dirty and unclear solution, I guess :)

Comment: Thank you, @Hutsi for your suggestion. The reason i perform insert/update right in modal, because in create action the commission_id is null so i can't save the modal, if i want to do it like this, i think i need to change to wizard-like entry, after save commission scheme then i show the detail entry and so on.

Comment: Your second suggestion i think would work, i just need to know if the selected records can be included as form input when form submited?